# can we monitor SAP java processes using jconsole?

Tags: java

I tried to attach SAP jstart.exe process PID to jconsole . I got error "Invalid process id:3468" .Do not think that the process did not exist.The process in running state.Please check your SAP java process connection to jconsole and put Screenshot here.

Comment: another process smdagent.exe with PID:3589 . Got the same error "Invalid process id:3589"

Comment: above two processes are java processes only ,I checked out in SAP Management console.